# Chrome master_preferences file appears to be encrypted

Tags: google-chrome, ssl, localhost

I am trying to disable the privacy error flag feature in Chrome; long story long, Chrome refuses to accept my local host's SSL certificate for a website I’m deploying in dev, and I don’t have time to troubleshoot manually signing another one through IIS.

It appears that Chrome’s dev team has removed the `remember-cert-error-decisions` feature from `chrome://flags` as part of a recent update.

I tried going the brute force route and disabling the privacy error flag in Chrome’s `master_preferences` file, but for some reason, it’s saved on my machine as an unrecognized file type and when I open it, instead of JSON, I get encrypted gobbledygook. Downloading a different version of Chrome through the Chromium channel didn’t help.

Below is the only JSON that appears in the file. The rest of it is just strings of random characters as shown in the attached screenshot:

```
{"distribution":{"make_chrome_default_for_user":true},"variations_seed":"
```

[image]

Comment: Good idea. See updated link in the edited section of my post.

Comment: Still no juice. The editor represents the unformatted portion as a parameter of 'variations_seed:'